# Set TypeScript compiler's base/working directory

Tags: typescript, compilation, tsc

It looks like TypeScript compiler resolves files relative to the location of the `tsconfig.json` file.

Is there a way to specify an alternative base directory, which will be used for relative paths resolution?

I want to use a generic `tsconfig.json` file to compile multiple projects in various directories.

[Here's the related question](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25430) in TypeScript official repository.

Answer (score 3):

I've got a similar problem as you but solved it with `tsconfig.json` in each project.

I have frontend and backend code and shared code between the two. It has the following directory structure.

```
/my-project
   /common
      *.ts
   /frontend
      *.ts
      tsconfig.json
   /backend
      /src
         *.ts
      tsconfig.json
```

Here's the `backend/tsconfig.json`:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "outDir": "./dist",
  ...
}
...
```

Typescript compiler automatically determines the greatest common ancestor directory, hence `rootDir`, of all `*.ts` files according to your `tsconfig.json`. You don't even need to specify `rootDir` explicitly because the compiler walks the hierarchy up to `my-project` and sets it as the root.

The import inside a `backend/some.ts` looks like:

```
import { Foo } from '../../common/some-shared';
```

Because of the automatic `rootDir` calculation of the compiler the only gotcha is that the output inside the `backend/dist` directory looks like this:

```
/dist
    /common
       *.js
    /backend
       /src
          *.js
```

I haven't figured out yet how I can get rid of the ugly `dist/backend/src` structure without using any copying or bundling with Webpack, etc prior to compilation. From what I searched it's (still) not possible to do that with the Typescript compiler only. Maybe someone has hints... Hope that helped for now.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you figured out how to get rid of `dist/backend/src` structure (especially `src` part :) )?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I investigated a little and it seems that it is outside of the scope of the Typescript compiler thus won't be implemented.